# ComboBox - disabling Keyboard manual input at runtime in vb6

Tags: combobox, vb6

My combo box STYLE property is 0 (Editable).
But for certain condition I want to disable the manual input.
I tried setting STYLE property to 2.But it throwing error saying it is read only property.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this in the Combo `KeyPress`. Set a module level boolean to indicate whether the combo can be edited:

```
Private m_ComboDisabled As Boolean
```

Then in your `KeyPress` event for the combo:

```
Private Sub Combo1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If m_ComboDisabled Then
        KeyAscii = 0
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Setting `KeyAscii = 0` in `KeyPress` swallows the keypress.

To be thorough, you'll also want to handle KeyDown:

```
Private Sub Combo1_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If m_ComboDisabled Then
        KeyCode = 0
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

As others have mentioned, this will not prevent right-click, paste though.

The best solution is to set `Combo1.Locked = true` when you want to disable any input (including right-click, paste).

Answer (score 2):

The old trick that jac mentions is VERY old, going back to VB3.  You don't want to use C-Pound's solution in this case either (sorry CP, no offense intended), because users can use the mouse to copy and paste text into the box.

Since VB4 any control that allows input has a Locked property, and this is what you want.  Set it to true, and nobody can type into the box.  Set it to false, and typing is again allowed.

Comment: `Locked` is the obvious way to go.

Comment: Great catch. I forgot about `Locked`.

Comment: unfortunatly locked stop also mouse click. So is right that user can't write any, but also can't select one of the option.

Answer (score 0):

The old trick to handle this was to fake the style change. Create 2 combobox controls that are identical except for style and show the one you want while hiding the other.